# Firebase Deployed successfully but still website is not rendering

Tags: reactjs, firebase

firebase is deployed successfully but when i click on the generated URL Website is not rendered and i get these errors in the console-

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()  /%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()  :manifest.json:1
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 5, Unexpected data after root element.      :manifest.json:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()  :manifest.json:1

Comment: Are you using github actions to host your application? If so, please share the firebase-hosting .yaml file(s) inside the .github/workflows directory

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying the mentioned assets are not located on your firebase hosting.

My guess is either...

You didn't build, in which case run...

```
npm run-script build; firebase deploy --only hosting
```

Or you don't have the assets located in your folder. For me at least, my file structure looks like this

```
/public/
index.html
manifest.json
/assets/
    /icon/
        favicon.png
```